# What is wrong with my circuit and how can I fix it?

Tags: oscillator, soldering, speakers, multivibrator, astable

This circuit used to work before I soldered it. When I initially soldered it, I used a 6V battery and it was oscillating, but the speaker was very quiet. I went with a 9V battery and I re-soldered some other parts because the speaker would still not produce any sound. As well, the LED would have a voltage of around 8V on its turn while the speaker would only have around 0.03V on its turn (this stayed the same even after I switched their places and even replaced them). Right now, the speaker makes no sound and the LED (which previously flashed up with each oscillation) no longer flashed either. I checked with a voltmeter and voltage was still there across the circuit and across the loads. I can assure you that no soldered part is touching another (I know this cuz I've spent a day looking at them).
I don't know what to do make the circuit function and for the speaker to make sound, please help.

[image]

Comment: *I used a 6V battery and it was oscillating, but the speaker was very quiet.* So the circuit was working, so that what you did after that broke it. You need to include a **schematic** before we can give a proper answer, use the schematic drawing tool that's available when you edit your question. Note that you might be expecting too much from this simple circuit. Include details of your speaker as it might have a low impedance and then it will be harder to get some volume out of it.

Comment: Photos of your "soldering skills" don't help so remove those. You have to determine (measure!) yourself if the connections are OK.

Comment: If you're new to soldering and have no experience how much is too much and had to redo a joint a few times, you might have cooked something. Here's a tip: ignore the rule that says to use a tip that is 2/3 as wide as the pad. Instead, use a pad twice as large as the pad if you can fit in.

Comment: The only thing that I'd worry about permanently frying on that board is the LED. The soldering job is very poor and the most likely culprit.

Comment: Are you trying to build a astable multi-vibrator like this: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html. I would suggest to first test it using a bread board. I usually start with a bread board, then a proto board, and if everything goes well, and if I need more than a couple of it, then I will us PCB.

Comment: You havre a loose lead on the images, I assume you are aware of that? (Black lead at the bottom)

Comment: If you want the speaker louder, just reduce the value of R4. Try 220 instead of 2k2.

Comment: Middle pin of the transistor, bottom left of the second image, doesn't look like it's well soldered.

Comment: @tlfong01:  Sakbaloch has assembled a **kit.** There's not much point in discussing prototyping on a breadboard before making a PCB.

Comment: Here is the OP's kit: http://www.audiowind.com/pdf/E-105.pdf

Comment: @JRE, Ah, I wrongly thought that the OP fabricated his own PCB. So he actually bought the kit with a schematic. So he can use a multi-meter and do point to point open/short tests to locate any faulty/fake/dry soldering joints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loud sound you cannot drive the speaker through such a high impedance like 2k2. Also, your oscillator works at too low frequency (10Hz if pots are down) so it acts like a DC signal.

The circuit I attached below oscilates at about 1kHz and drives the speaker with higher power so the sound should be louder. Try to change C3 a little if necessary.

[image]

[image]